# Passing anonymous type to annotation

Tags: java, generics, lambda, annotations, anonymous-class

I want to pass an anonymous type to an annotation. As I dont know how to explain my problem in words properly, I'll just explain my intention and my code.

I'm currently writing a serializer/deserializer for Java to JSON. Every class then needs to implement a specific interface to be serializable and every field also needs an annotation, so my serializer knows which fields to serialize.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
public @interface SerializeField {
    Class<? extends Formatter> formatter();
}
```

Now i added the ability to specify a formatter that generates a string for a field.

```
public interface Formatter<T> {
    public abstract String format(T object);
}
```

This works fine when I just create a new class that implements Formatter but does not work when I create an anonymous class or use a lambda expression.

```
public class Test implements Javonable {

    //This does not work
    Formatter<BigDecimal> bigDecimalFormatter = (BigDecimal object) -> object.toString();

    @SerializeField(formatter = bigDecimalFormatter.getClass())
    private BigDecimal bigDecimal; // ^ The value for annotation attribute SerializeField.formatter must be a class literal

    //This does work
    @SerializeField(formatter = BigIntegerFormatter.class)
    private BigInteger bigInteger;

    public class BigIntegerFormatter implements Formatter<BigInteger> {
        @Override
        public String format(BigInteger object) {
            return object.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I don't see or is there a solution for that? In the end I just want to be able to pass a Formatter as simple as possible without having to create a new class each time.

Comment: Is this really less work than having, e.g. a method `Map<String,String> serialize() { return Map.of("bigDecimal", …, "bigInteger", …); }` in every class?

Comment: Well, there is already a method serialize() in the interface Javonable with a standard implementation. Stuff like primitives and other Objects that implement Javonable already get serialized, just classes that dont implement javonable are a problem. They are the reason I need formatters. Now I just want to be able to define a Formatter for just one field using an anonymous class